# Understanding Requests from Google Places API for Web w Place Autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

We are considering using Google Places API for a new web application project and I believe we are vastly underestimating the number of requests we would use.

We would be using place search, Maps JavaScript API map load to grab Place IDs from Google as well as Place Autocomplete to help users find the defined location. So my questions are:

- Would the Autocomplete be considered a request on every keystroke?
- Would if also be a request when we select the suggestion (Places API)
  and update to Map?

I have seen that with the premium Plan autocompletes use 0.1 Maps API Credit, while JavaScript API map load is 1 and Places API is 2 credits. Trying to understand how to count before the 150k limit and after

Comment: Things changed recently. On June 11 2018 Google changes pricing model and usage quotas: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment of your question, Google is making some drastic changes to their collective maps API usage rates.  Starting June 11th, [the new pricing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/) will go into effect.

> Would the Autocomplete be considered a request on every keystroke?

As of now, places autocomplete is counted on every keystroke.  Starting June 11th, you have the option to switch to [session-based billing](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/). They have different pricing rates which can be see in the pricing sheet link.  Depending on your application, you'll want to use the option that minimizes API calls.  I think if your use case is one time selecting of location by your users then you're better off with billing by keystroke.

> Would if also be a request when we select the suggestion (Places API)
>   and update to Map?

Selecting a suggestion from Places API would not incur an API request (requesting the suggestions does), but updating a google map using the Map API would use an API request.

The 150k daily limit is going away in favor of the new billing rates, so I would suggest you look into that now. There are some free unlimited services still offered, like the Google Maps Embed API.  Loading a map using the Embed API is not counted towards any billing (as of now).